# Nodejs & express redirection to https not working for homepage

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm using express to serve static files on my vps.
I created two servers `http` and `https` like so:

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(httpPort);

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(httpsPort);
```

By using a middlewear like below:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) { 
    !req.secure 
        ? res.redirect(301, path.join('https://', req.get('Host'), req.url)) 
        : next();
});
```

Most of my requests are well redirected to https. However, when loading my website with only the domain without ssl (http://example.com) and without any child routes (like http://example.com/contact), this is not redirecting to https.

### Edit

I serve static files (an angular 4 app compiled for production):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, distFolder)));
```

And I have as route what follows:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) ={ 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, distFolder, 'index.html'));
});
```

---

Can you help me to find out what I missed ? I didn't find answer for this exact issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was the issue: I was serving the public folder **before** the security test...

So here are the steps now:

```
// Step 1: Test all incoming requests (from http and https servers).

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) 
        return next();

    var target = url.format({ // Thanks Linus for the advice!
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: req.hostname,
        pathname: req.url
    });

    res.redirect(301, target);
});

// Step 2: Serve static files.

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'your/dist/folder')));

// Step 3: Build routes (in my case with * because of the SPA).

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'your/dist/folder', 'index.html'));
});
```

Now it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `node-rest-client` for redirecting properly to any URL.

You can install it by `npm install node-rest-client`

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use other third-party packages for the moment. I really want to understand why my code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`path.join` is meant for joining together path elements, and should not be used to construct URLs. In your example the redirect url will be missing one of the leading slashes.

```
> path.join('https://', 'example.com', '/hello/world')
'https:/example.com/hello/world'
```

Instead you can use `url.format`, which will construct a proper url.

```
> url.format({ protocol: 'https:', host: 'example.com', pathname: '/hello/world' })
'https://example.com/hello/world'
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.secure) return next()

  const target = url.format({
    protocol: 'https:',
    host: req.get('Host'),
    pathname: req.url
  })

  res.redirect(301, target)
})
```

Comment: Hi Linus, thanks for that advice, I'll use it from now. but he issue is still here. However, I have a lead: I use Express to serve static files (an angular 4 app). When I only return a string with the response instead of the angular main page (`app.get('*', (req, res) =>  res.send('Hello'))`) it works ! But I have a second issue, I don't know why in chrome, if I write for example test in the path name then load the site, the url is composed by twenty times the domain name! :O

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you tried the resolution of this on the Web server layer not the application layer, receive both secured and non-secured requests/traffic through both 80 and 443.

Comment: You mean from a server like nginx or apache? If so, I only want to user node.js/express.